# Add CKEditor add-ons to <pe:ckEditor>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ckeditor, add-on, primefaces-extensions

I am using [PrimeFaces Extensions `<pe:ckEditor>`](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/ckEditor.jsf) which is basically a server side JSF component which generates the necessary HTML/CSS/JS code output for CKEditor. It works fine, however I have a new requirement which requires me to use either the [PBCKCODE](http://ckeditor.com/addon/pbckcode) or the [syntaxhighlighter](http://ckeditor.com/addon/syntaxhighlight) add-on of CKEditor.

I have successfully created a customized version with those add-ons from [their website](http://ckeditor.com/demo). However, I have no clue how to integrate those add-ons in `<pe:ckEditor>`. How can I integrate those add-ons in `<pe:ckEditor>`?

Comment: @BaluC any help on this? Also after your changes my question is out of featured why?

Comment: @BalusC thanks for your edit and reply can you suggest any alternative very simple editor like Stackoverflow have which i can use In my JSF application

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use the CKEditor directly in stead of using it through pe:ckEditor? At least thats what I did in our project.

Comment: Because i want a simple editor like Stackoverflow also when i tried to modify the CkEditor to add code tag is not worked so i was thinking to use it can you help me to resolve above issue